# List Tuple more than 8 items

Tags: c#, .net, tuples

Can anyone help the following List Tuple more than 8 elements is not working:

```
List<Tuple<int, string, double, string, int, string, double, Tuple<int, string>>> tpl = new 
List<Tuple<int, string, double, string, int, string, double, Tuple<int, string>>>();
tpl.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "ABC", 100.123, "XYZ", 1, "ABC", 100.123, new Tuple<int, string>(100, "My Rest Item")));

foreach(var k in tpl)
        listBox1.Items.Add(k.Item1.ToString() + " ---> " + k.Item2.ToString() + " ---> " + k.Item3.ToString() + " ---> " +
        k.Item4.ToString() + " ---> " + k.Item5.ToString() + " ---> " + k.Item6.ToString() + " ---> " +
        k.Item7.ToString() + " ---> " + k.Rest.Item1.ToString());
```

It gives following error

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<int,string,double,string,int,string,double,System.Tuple<int,string>>>.Add(System.Tuple<int,string,double,string,int,string,double,System.Tuple<int,string>>)`'
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\Hewlett
>   Packard\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs    68  17  WindowsFormsApplication1
>   and  Error    2   Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   '`System.Tuple<int,string,double,string,int,string,double,System.Tuple<System.Tuple<int,string>>>`'
>   to
>   '`System.Tuple<int,string,double,string,int,string,double,System.Tuple<int,string>>`' C:\Users\Hewlett
>   Packard\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs    68  25  WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Aside from anything else - don't do this! Create your own named type with the relevant properties etc.

Answer (score 22):

The problem is with the last argument to [`Tuple.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Look carefully at how the argument return value is defined:

```
public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>
    Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(
    T1 item1,
    T2 item2,
    T3 item3,
    T4 item4,
    T5 item5,
    T6 item6,
    T7 item7,
    T8 item8
)
```

Basically, that *wraps* `T8` in a `Tuple<T8>` automatically - and somewhat unhelpfully.

You can use `new` instead:

```
var value = new Tuple<<int, string, double, string, int, string, double,
                      Tuple<int, string>>
    (1, "ABC", 100.123, "XYZ", 1, "ABC", 100.123,
     new Tuple<int, string>(100, "My Rest Item"));
```

That's pretty ghastly though. It might be better to create some static methods yourself, e.g.

```
public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8, T9>>
    Create(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5, T6 t6, T7 t7, T8 t8, T9 t9)
{
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8, T9>>
        (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, Tuple.Create(t8, t9)); 
}
```

(with as many overloads as you need)

or possibly an extension method on `Tuple<T1 ... T7>`:

```
public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest>
    With(this Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7> tuple,
         TRest rest)
{
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest>(
        tuple.Item1, 
        tuple.Item2, 
        tuple.Item3, 
        tuple.Item4, 
        tuple.Item5, 
        tuple.Item6, 
        tuple.Item7,
        rest);
}
```

Then you could use:

```
var value = Tuple.Create(1, "ABC", 100.123, "XYZ", 1, "ABC", 100.123)
                 .With(Tuple.Create(100, "My Rest Item"));
```

Personally I'd try to avoid having this size of tuple entirely though - create a named type with the appropriate properties, instead.

Comment: So that would be a bug in the declaration of that factory method then? I can't really see a point of doing that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I suspect there's *some* reason for it, but it's not entirely clear what it is - it's certainly unhelpful in this use case.

Answer (score 8):

In C#7

```
var tup = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, "nine");
var one = tup.Item1;
var nine = tup.Item9;
```

Comment: very relevant to mention it

Comment: Note that this creates a `ValueTuple` and not a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand why myself, but the code will work when you use `new Tuple<>` instead of `Tuple.Create`:

```
tpl.Add
( new Tuple<int, string, double, string, int, string, double, Tuple<int, string>>
  ( 1
  , "ABC"
  , 100.123
  , "XYZ"
  , 1
  , "ABC"
  , 100.123
  , Tuple.Create(100, "My Rest Item")
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I struggled for many hours and I finally made it work with the approach below:
method:

```cs
internal static Tuple<List<double>, List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, List<int>, List<int>, Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>> YourMethodName(int something)

// do method work

return new Tuple<List<double>, List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, List<int>, List<int>, Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>> (itme1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, new Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>(item8, item9));
```

I was using return `Tuple.Create(item1, item2 etc)` and it was working until I tried to use **item9** (it only can use 8 max, even if item 8 is a nested tuple, then after many hours of google and frustration I found this out.)