# Should we use Tuple or ValueTuple for reference-type only variables?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, c#-7.0, valuetuple

There's many questions contains only difference between `Tuple(class)` vs `ValueTuple(struct)`
All gone with `ValueTuple` where there's no **GC** pressure. But I don't get enough with why `ValueTuple` accepts all data-types then? why not just `ValueTuple` accepts only structs as they designed as a struct.

At a glance. Is it safe and more performance for use Reference-Types with ValueTuple?

example

`ValueTuple<CarClass, EngineClass> CarBody`

or shall we go

`Tuple<CarClass, EngineClass> CarBody`

All example I see contains `ValueTuple<int, int, long, structs only>` Is it designed for that purpose only? Many of code I use use `ValueTuple<ReferenceTypes>`

Comment: What do you mean with unsafe? References in a struct get their references copied (the reference pointing to an instance, not the instance itself) if you assign the struct to another variable. Also instead of `ValueTuple<CarClass, EngineClass>` you should use the `(CarClass Car, EngineClass Engine)` syntax as it allows you to name your members instead of having them called Item1, Item2 and so on, making them less error-prone.

Answer (score 7):

> Why not just `ValueTuple` accepts only structs as they designed as a struct?

Structs always could have references. Nothing stops you from using `KeyValuePair<CarClass, EngineClass>` either, where `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is also a value type.

> All gone with `ValueTuple` where there's no **GC** pressure.

There must be a misunderstanding here. Value tuples with reference type arguments will be tracked by the GC, of course. It just means there is no *additional* pressure because of grouping some references into a `ValueTuple`. On the other hand, using `Tuple<>` means an extra reference, which is obviously has some additional GC cost.

> Is it safe for use Reference-Types with ValueTuple?

It's a bit unclear what do you mean safety here but yes, it is certainly safe.

Whether it is better than the other depends on the usage. Many parameters (`ValueTuple<int, int, long, other structs>`) may result in large values. If you often pass such big values around methods it may end up worse performance than just passing a reference. But if that does not matter you are totally ok with value tuples, which have a convenient syntax support (and they still can be passed by reference by the `in` or `ref` modifier if needed).

Comment: Gyorgy. Thanks for your answer yes its helpful. I mean safety(performance, good approach)

Comment: I was searching about If Tuple exceed 7 elements they will create a new ValueTuple at element 8, Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRest>  https://prnt.sc/xvlf6b  See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533742/how-to-create-a-list-of-valuetuple-more-than-eight-values

Comment: That's why in my case rather than creating class which hold CarClass, CarEngine inside MyCar class. then creating a List for that I see a Tuples directly can be easy and save creating many useless classes which no need for generic usage. only internally. And Am still not sure which is better for reference-types only Tuple or ValueTuple :)