# Pattern Matching with 8 conditions in C#: File.Exists returns false, but the file does exist

Tags: c#

Consider the program from below. The idea should be as follows: In the `Main` method, `AreAllArgumentsPassedAndValid()` is called that checks certain parameters for correctness. The check is carried out using so-called tuple matching. A total of 7 + 1 conditions should be checked. For the sake of simplicity, I have replaced 7 of these conditions with boolean variables with permanently assigned values, because I am sure that they will be checked correctly. I only left the last condition as it appears in my original program. In this last condition, the string is checked whether it is not empty or zero and then checked whether the file exists (the string thus represents the path).

The problem: I have found that the file is never found if I have at least 8 conditions in my switch. But: As soon as I delete a condition from the switch, for example, `cond7`, I only have 7 conditions in total and in this case the file is correctly searched for and a correct value is returned, depending on whether the file exists or not.

It also doesn't matter where I put my file - I tried to put the file directly under `C:\`. It is not found there either. But if I call `File.Exists` separately, not in the return/switch, the search for the file works correctly.

My question is the following: What influence does the number of arguments in return/switch have on the correct work of `File.Exists(oFileName)`? I've tried debugging the `File.Exists(oFileName)` method when I have 8 conditions in the switch, but that didn't bring me up to the solution.

Information about my PCs: All of them have Win 10 x64 and the same .NET version. And on all of them is the issue the same.

The whole program with 8 conditions in the return/switch:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PatternMatchingTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static class Constants
        {
            public const string ProgramSide = "PROGRAM_SIDE";
            public const string OldFileName = "OLD_FILE_NAME";
            public const string NewFileName = "NEW_FILE_NAME";
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string oldFilePath = @"C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Test.txt";
            
            Console.WriteLine(AreAllArgumentsPassedAndValid());
            Console.ReadKey();
            
            string AreAllArgumentsPassedAndValid()
            {
                string oFileName = oldFilePath;
                bool cond1 = true, cond2 = true, cond3 = true, cond4 = true, cond5 = true, cond6 = false, cond7 = false;
                return (cond1,
                        cond2,
                        cond3,
                        cond4,
                        cond5,
                        cond6,
                        cond7,
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(oFileName) && File.Exists(oFileName))
                    switch
                    {
                        (false, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) => $"Invalid number of arguments. 3 arguments are expected.",
                        (_, false, _, _, _, _, _, _) => $"Missing {Constants.ProgramSide} argument.",
                        (_, _, false, _, _, _, _, _) => $"Missing {Constants.OldFileName} argument.",
                        (_, _, _, false, _, _, _, _) => $"Missing {Constants.NewFileName} argument.",
                        (_, _, _, _, false, _, _, _) => $"Argument {Constants.ProgramSide} has invalid value.",
                        (_, _, _, _, _, true, _, _) => $"Argument {Constants.OldFileName} has invalid value: null or empty. Expected: path to a file.",
                        (_, _, _, _, _, _, true, _) => $"Argument {Constants.NewFileName} has invalid value: null or empty. Expected: path to a file.",
                        (_, _, _, _, _, _, _, false) => $"File {oFileName} does not exist.",
                        (true, true, true, true, true, false, false, true) => string.Empty
                    };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `AreAllArgumentsPassedAndValid` method with only 7 conditions - in this case the program works as it should:

```
string AreAllArgumentsPassedAndValid()
{
    string oFileName = oldFilePath;
    bool cond1 = true, cond2 = true, cond3 = true, cond4 = true, cond5 = true, cond6 = false, cond7 = false;
        return (cond1,
                cond2,
                cond3,
                cond4,
                cond5,
                cond6,

                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(oFileName) && File.Exists(oFileName))
                switch
                {
                    (false, _, _, _, _, _, _) => $"Invalid number of arguments. 3 arguments are expected.",
                    (_, false, _, _, _, _, _) => $"Missing {Constants.ProgramSide} argument.",
                    (_, _, false, _, _, _, _) => $"Missing {Constants.OldFileName} argument.",
                    (_, _, _, false, _, _, _) => $"Missing {Constants.NewFileName} argument.",
                    (_, _, _, _, false, _, _) => $"Argument {Constants.ProgramSide} has invalid value.",
                    (_, _, _, _, _, true, _) => $"Argument {Constants.OldFileName} has invalid value: null or empty. Expected: path to a file.",
                    (_, _, _, _, _, _, false) => $"File {oFileName} does not exist.",
                    (true, true, true, true, true, false,  true) => string.Empty
                };
}
```

Comment: You get an interesting error message on [dotnetfiddle.net with that code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4VfIID) "Operation could destabilize the runtime.". Maybe stick with types.

Comment: I think a way around the issue is to just create sub-tuples so that no single tuple has more than 7 items. like `((c1, c2, c3, c4), (c5, c6, c7, c8))` Then you could do comparisons like `((true, _, _, _), _)` which is a bit shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating a tuple with 8 values, it [starts to get weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263598/list-tuple-more-than-8-items). The better approach is to create an object with named properties, since I'd argue the tuple you have is impossible to read.

Comment: That's the `Tuple` class, the OP is dealing with value tuples.

Comment: @juharr They are defined [in the same way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-8?view=netcore-3.1#type-parameters).

Comment: @GSerg Yeah I was just looking up the source code, so the same issue would exist.

Comment: @Noah Stahl OK, understood. I overlooked this limitation with 8 items.